# How to get the last login session details of a user in Keycloak using Keycloak rest endpoints?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

How to get the last login session details of a user in Keycloak using keycloak rest endpoints?

Example:

```
builder.append(OAuth2Constants.AUDIENCE+"="+clientId+"&");
builder.append(OAuth2Constants.GRANT_TYPE+"="+OAuth2Constants.UMA_GRANT_TYPE+"&");
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);

//String keycloakURL = keyCloakCFGBean.getCreateRefreshSession();
String keycloakURL="http://10.10.8.113:10004/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token";
keycloakURL = keycloakURL.replace("{realm}", realmName);

URL url = new URL(keycloakURL);
httpURLConnection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
if (headers != null && headers.size() > 0) {
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> itr = headers.entrySet().iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, String> entry = itr.next();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}

outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
outputStreamWriter.write(builder.toString());
outputStreamWriter.flush();
```

Answer (score 21):

So there are a couple of scenarios here. All of this information assumes that you have an appropriate bearer token that you are sending in the header of the request for authentication/authorisation, and requires that you have sufficient admin privileges in the Keycloak realm.

I've not gone into detail in terms of the precise code you write in a particular language, but hopefully the instructions are clear in terms of what you need your code to do.

**Sessions**

If you are interested in ACTIVE user sessions specifically, you can use the API endpoint as described at: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_getsessions

That is:
`GET /{realm}/users/{id}/sessions`
e.g. the full URL would be:
`https://{server}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/sessions`

In the response there will be a property called `lastAccess` that will contain a number that is the usual UNIX milliseconds since 1/1/1970. If you take that number, you can then parse it in your language of choice (Java from the looks of it?) to get the date/time in the format that you require.

**All Logins**

However I suspect what you really want is to look at the last login across all of the stored information in Keycloak, not just active user sessions, so for that you need to look for the Realm EVENTS. Note that Keycloak only stores events for a certain amount of time, so if it's older than that then you won't find any entries. You can change how long events are stored for in the events config page of the realm admin console.

To get all realm events you call the endpoint mentioned here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_getevents (Search for "Get events Returns all events, or filters them based on URL query parameters listed here" if the link doesn't take you straight there).

i.e.
`GET /{realm}/events`
e.g. the full URL would be:  `https://{server}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/events`

You will need to filter the results based on "type" (i.e. so that you only have events of type "LOGIN"), and if you want to check a specific user you would also want to filter the results on `userId` based on the ID of that user account.

You can perform both of these filters as part of the request, to save you having to get the full list of events and filter it client-side. To filter in the request you do something like the following:

`https://{server}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/events?type=LOGIN&user={id}`

From the resultant JSON you can then get the result with the highest value of the `time` property, that represents that login event. The `time` property will be a UNIX time of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 again, so again you can convert this to a format that is appropriate to you once you have it.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Helpful answer, in my case I just had to enable the events too because the result was an empty array. Pick Events from them menu (next to groups, users, sessions), then config tab and enable save for Login Events. You can also pick the categories of events you want to save.

Answer (score -3):

use Keycloak rest Api

```
${keycloakUri}/admin/realms/${keycloakRealm}/users
```

and you will get a response as JWT. Decode it and you will get all the info related to the user.

OR you may use the java client API for example by

```
Keycloak kc = KeycloakBuilder.builder() 
        .serverUrl("https://localhost:8443/auth")
        .realm("master")
        .username("admin") 
        .password("admin") 
        .clientId("Mycli") 
        .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build()) 
        .build();

CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
credential.setValue("test123");

UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
user.setUsername("testuser2");
user.setFirstName("Test2");
user.setLastName("User2");
user.setEmail("aaa@bbb.com");
user.setCredentials(Arrays.asList(credential));
user.setEnabled(true);
user.setRealmRoles(Arrays.asList("admin"));

UsersResource usersResource  = kc.realm("my-realem").users();
UserResource userResource = usersResource.get("08afb701-fae5-40b4-8895-e387ba1902fb");
```

you will get the list of users. Filter by user ID then you will find all user info.

Comment: No last login info in user's info